# Why am I getting a AXServer error when sharing data via Snapchat SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, snapchat

I am using the [example xcode project](https://github.com/Snapchat/creative-kit-sample/tree/master/ios) for sharing media between my app and Snapchat directly. I have successfully authenticated my app by this point (it loads bitmoji + user info and I can print the access token). The code that causes the error is invoked after the UIPicker has selected an image:

from line 38 of [MediaPickerViewController.swift](https://github.com/Snapchat/creative-kit-sample/blob/master/ios/CreativeKitSample/Classes/UI/ViewControllers/MediaPickerViewController.swift)

```
fileprivate func shareImage(image: UIImage) {
    let snapPhoto = SCSDKSnapPhoto(image: image)
    let snapContent = SCSDKPhotoSnapContent(snapPhoto: snapPhoto)

    // Send it over to Snapchat. This produced the error below
    snapAPI.startSending(snapContent)
}
```

Then when you pick an image from the gallery:

```
2020-03-23 17:49:54.487603-0700 CreativeKitSample[20966:5903027] 
[AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:
Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:20969
```

This is running on my iPhone, debugging over USB. I'm new to Swift development, and my best guess is that my app is developer certificate signed, perhaps it is sandboxed on iOS 13 from communication with prod apps? Or is the `AXServer` more of a Core UI thing or Accessibility? This project uses Interface Builder/Storyboards. I tried disabling `accessibility` checkbox on UI elements. I'm at a loss here, searching for AXServer permission errors has not been useful.

some AX errors:

- https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController/issues/402
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120696 (clue that it may be inter-app permission)
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203618 (sandbox extension?)

Comment: I'm an idiot. When I created my Apple Developer Cert and Provisioning Profile, I had a collision with the package identifier, so I changed it in the provisioning settings but neglected to update the snapchat portal's bundle ID. Leaving the question here as closed for anyone else. They could make their error a bit more descriptive...

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot. When I created my Apple Developer Cert and Provisioning Profile, I had a collision with the package identifier, so I changed it in the provisioning settings but neglected to update the snapchat portal's bundle ID. Leaving the question here for anyone else with the same problem.

They could make their error a bit more descriptive...

Comment: I have the same error, but nothing to do with snapchat.  Please make your solution a bit more descriptive by including more detail.  What, exactly, did you do to eliminate the error (step-by-step)?

Answer (score -2):

I got maybe a solution... I'm dismissing before the current View Controller, then present the SFSafariViewController.

Using following Code does help me out! (Xcode 11.3.1, macOS 10.14.6, iOS 13.3)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
    // code goes here
})

// my solution...
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```